# how to create an address value in solidity

Tags: solidity

I have a simple prgram

```
contract Xyz {
       struct A {
              address x;
              string y;
        }
        mapping( string => A) someMap;
        function record(string y) {
             xAddress = How do i create an address?
            someMap[y] = A(xAddress, 'test')
      }
      getAddress(string y) public constant returns (address) {
             return someMap[y].x;
     }
}
```

How do i create a address value?

One way I know I can do it is create a dummy contract and then create an instance to get the address. is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

you could use `msg.sender` which represents the sender's address (or `address(this)` for the contract address). 
or you could initiate the variable using a hexadecimal value like `0x123`(an address is 20 bytes);

```
 contract Xyz {
           struct A {
                  address x;
                  string y;
            }
            mapping( string => A) someMap;
            function record(string y) {
                 xAddress = msg.sender;
                someMap[y] = A(xAddress, 'test')
          }
          getAddress(string y) public constant returns (address) {
                 return someMap[y].x;
         }
    }
```